# Symbol value in .symtab for executable object files

Tags: executable, elf

I've read that ELF executable object files are not relocatable and symbols in its .symtab has an absolute address/"value" as opposed to "relative offset" for relocatable objects. Is my understanding correct?

If so, then how is the absolute address determined? Since the vast majority of executable object files reside in ROM (e.g. HDD) and not RAM, wouldn't you need to load the file into RAM before executing? Wouldn't that be the same as "relocating"?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A non-position-independent executable is linked to be loaded (into RAM) at a fixed address. For example, on 32-bit x86 Linux, the default linked-at address is `0x8048000`. This address could be changed with e.g. `-Ttext` linker argument.

The symbol values in `.symtab` section are indeed absolute, and assume that the binary is loaded at the address it was linked to load at.

> executable object files reside in ROM (e.g. HDD) and not RAM, wouldn't you need to load the file into RAM before executing?

Yes, but that doesn't have anything to do with symbols being relative or absolute.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I didn't phrase my questions very well. There were actually 2 questions:
-I was confused about the definition for "relocatable"; my previous thinking is that relocatable means the file can be moved anywhere in memory while "not relocatable" means the file can't be moved (i.e. from ROM to RAM). Sounds silly looking at it now :)
-Executable files are not relocatable, and if I read your answer correctly, that actually means it will be loaded at a predetermined absolute address specified in the .symtab? If that's the case, what if there is already something else loaded there?